# Matlab Audio processing

Tags: matlab, audio, equalizer, channel

i've been assigned a homework that includes audio processing in matlab, what i got to do is get at least 3 channels of different frequencies in a song, and increase the dB output depending on the channel. It's got to work like an equalizer but using only 3 channels. My biggest problem here is getting a frequency and magnitude values and save it into variables separated in channels (Low, Mid and High) frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read your file using wavread
2. *Specify* the filter using **fdesign** ([FDesign Help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.html)) where you need 3 filters lowpass, bandpass and High pass. (You may need to decimate)
3. Use **design** to actually design the filter from above specification. You need to specify & design thrice as you have 3 channels. This can be made into a function and wavread output can be passed to this.
4. Finally use **filter** command to actually filter the data. (Again 3 filters)
5. Now you have 3 outputs which belong to 3 frequencies. (Use Matlab help its really good)

PS: I assume you have Signal Processing Toolbox.